# Import using gulp

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I am trying to use `ES2106` import in Angular 1.5, built with the gulp and getting

> couldn't process source due to parse error
>       'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

I have included babel also in gulp build.

Also, my .eslintrc is:

```
"parserOptions": {
"ecmaVersion": 6,
"sourceType": "module",
"allowImportExportEverywhere": true,
"ecmaFeatures": {
  "modules": true,
  "arrowFunctions": true,
  "classes": true
}
```